# Stacked glyphicons with Font Awesome

Tags: css, glyphicons

I have the `fa-circle-thin` in which i want to place a glyphicon, so that it looks like there is a round border around my glyphicon. I just want to know if this is even possible?

I've tried following:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <span class="circle">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
            </span>
            <h4 class="service-heading">Lorem</h4>
            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima maxime quam architecto quo inventore harum ex magni, dicta impedit.</p>
        </div>
```

However the two icons shows up side by side. I made a class for my FA that looks like this:

```
.circle:before {
    font-family: fontawesome-webfont;
    text-decoration: none;
    content: "\f1db";
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle/codepen?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u4gdtmbp/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use `border-radius: 50%` instead of trying to position two glyphs (plus you can style the border!). I'm also centering things with `text-align: center` and by matching the `line-height` and `height` values:

```css
.circle {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.alt {
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: red;
    color: red;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  
</div>

<div class="circle alt">
  
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that, but in my opinion it looks very pixelated

Comment: how would i get the star to be exactly in the middle of the border?

Comment: This renders as centered in Windows but is off-center in at least OS X... This is most likely an issue with the font implementations between operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

How about using posiiton:absolute?

```
.glyphicon{
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 15px;
}
```

Result: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/hw4yy245/)

Comment: Its possible, but then i have to fiddle my way towards the right left